# magento product count for attribute

Tags: magento, count, attributes, product

how to show product count on attribute?

code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Category/View.php

```
public function getAllManu()
{
  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
  $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
              ->setEntityTypeFilter($product->getResource()->getTypeId())
              ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', 'product_properties');
  $attribute = $attributes->getFirstItem()->setEntity($product->getResource());
  $product_properties = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
  return $product_properties;  
}
```

view.phtml

```
<select class="form-control" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
  <option>Select</option>
  <?php foreach ($this->getAllManu() as $product_properties): ?>
   <option value="<?php Mage::getURL() ?>catalogsearch/advanced/result/?product_properties[]=<?php echo $product_properties['value'] ?>"><?php echo $product_properties['label'] ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/291999

Answer (score 0):

Gokhan,use count() function count  the collection item collection

```
   <select class="form-control" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
  <option>Select</option>
  <?php foreach ($this->getAllManu() as $product_properties): ?>

     $productcollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('product_properties', $product_properties['value'])
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('status',array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED));;
    $productcollection = $productcollection->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currcategory),true);
    $productcollection->count();
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>


 $rel_products  ->count();
```

Comment: I could not. :/ Could you give an example?

Comment: are you want collection filter over all product collection ya current categroy product collection????

Comment: current category product